# Trying to enter the values of a csv file into a mysql database using python

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have trying to upload a csv file into mysql using python but i keep getting the following error

`ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-9cec642e378c> in <module>()
      8 csv_data = csv.reader(contents)
      9 for row in csv_data:
---> 10         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO finally(id,string1,string2,num1,num2,num3,num4,string3,string4,num5) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',row)
     11         print (row)
     12 mydb.commit()`

`~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py in execute(self, operation, params, multi)
    496                 if psub.remaining != 0:
    497                     raise errors.ProgrammingError(
--> 498                         "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement")
    499 
    500         if multi:`

`programmingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

I dont know what else to do because the number of parameters match the number of parameters in the table and the number of '?' are also the same(number of parameters =10), I dont know how to proceed. Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: Generally, please add code snippet you're running when getting an error.
And example or full csv file you're reading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSV Row is longer than 10 entries. That is what this error means.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `print(len(row))` statement to see if every row contains exactly 10 arguments.
Maybe there is an empty row, for example.